# How can I join an array from an intermediate point to the end or the end - 1?

Tags: powershell

I need to compare files throughout two directory structures. The base of the directories starts at the second element in the `DirectoryName` property. However, I do not know how many additional elements there will be in the path. Using `999` as the end of the range works, but surely there is a better way to do this.

```
PS>Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.DirectoryName.Split('\')[2..999] -join '\'
    }
```

Using a range of `[2..-1]` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`[2..-1]` doesn't work, because the *array of indices* created with `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#range-operator-), in this case is `2, 1, 0, -1`**, which is not what you intended.

Unfortunately, **as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4, the only way to refer to *all remaining* elements (or all remaining elements except the *last N*) is via an expression based on the array's *element count*, which requires you to capture the array in a *variable* first**:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $components = $_.DirectoryName.Split('\')
        $components[2..($components.Count-1)] -join '\'
    }
```

**Future outlook:** Providing a convenient index syntax that allows referencing all remaining elements (with `[2..]`) as well as all remaining elements except the last `$n` (with something like `[2..@-$n]`), is the subject of [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7940).

Note: A pipeline-based solution via `Select-Object -Skip 2`, as shown in [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071435/45375), is convenient, but noticeably *slower* than an array-slicing solution.

---

As for **what you tried**:

**Providing a *fixed* upper bound such as `999` that is known to always be higher than the true element count works IF AND ONLY IF (a) that bound is known and (b) is low enough not to cause memory / performance problems.**

Therefore, using something like `2..([int]::MaxValue-1)` is *not* an option.

(In practice, in PowerShell Core the highest index you can use is `[int]::MaxValue - 1048576` (`[int]::MaxValue - [Math]::Pow(2, 20))`) - but generating an array with that many elements (serving as indices) with `..` is prohibitively slow and memory-intensive).

---

**If performance is paramount**, use a solution based on `.Substring()` that simply omits the path prefix based on the input path:

```
$inputPath = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents"

# Determine the length of the prefix 
# comprising the input path's first 2 path components.
$prefixLength = ($inputPath -replace '^(.+?\\.+?\\).*', '$1').Length

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $inputPath |
 ForEach-Object {
   $_.DirectoryName.Substring($prefixLength)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, skip the first 2.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Documents |
  ForEach { ($_.DirectoryName.Split('\') | select -skip 2) -join '\' }
```

If you're trying to delete the first 2 folders in the fullname, here's another way.  The replace method doesn't use regex, but is case sensitive.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents" | 
  foreach { $_.fullname.replace('C:\Users\','')}
```